# how does $(this) work when nothing is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I just got into caching my jquery objects but not sure how to properly do it when using (this).

Also the only time I know how to use (this) is when its inside a click object or function so like:

```
$(".trigger").click(function () {
    if ($(this).hasClass('toggle')) {
        $(this).closest("td").next().find(".clueless > div").slideUp();
        $(this).removeClass('toggle');
    } else {
        $(this).closest("td").next().find(".clueless > div").slideDown();
        $(this).addClass('toggle');
    }
});
```

so if I wanted to cache the `$(this).closest("td").next().find(".clueless > div")` the only thing I could think would be:

```
var $something = $(".trigger").find(this).closest("td").next().find(".clueless > div");
```

Comment: $(".trigger").find(this) should == this

Comment: There's no reason to cache the whole `$(this).foo().bar().baz()...` thing because you're using it only once.

Comment: Also,  you can use `.end()` after `.find()` (etc.) instead of calling `.removeClass()` on a new line.

Comment: Why don't just cache it like `var el = $(this).closest("td").next().find(".clueless > div")` but as someone mentioned, if you are only using it once you don't need to cache it. Only one of the statement in if or else will trigger. I guess you could cache it if you want to save a few characters. It would make more sense to cache `$(this)` inside of your click handler

Comment: Also, I'm not really sure what the question is. What does "when nothing is selected" mean? Is the click event the actual use case?

Comment: @Juhana There's actually very good reasons to do so. Stay DRY and improve readability.

Comment: @plalx Granted, that is a good reason.

Comment: So ya im using the class .trigger on a bunch of elements that will be independently opened and closed so to improve performance I want to cache the selection. Thanks all! I dont know why I didnt think to put it inside the click function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will not completely re-iterate how the `this` keyword works, but there's an exhaustive explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/javascript-this-keyword).

#### In JS when the default `this` behaviour is not altered

Keeping things simple, to know the object to which the `this` keyword refers to you can simply look at the left-side of the `.` in a function invocation.

For example, in `myObj.someFunction()`, the `this` keyword within `someFunction` will point to `myObj` (that is unless the function has been bound using [`Function.prototype.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Function/bind)).

If the function is not invoked on an object, such as `someFunction()`, then `this` will point to the global object which is `window` in browsers.

This is also the case within anonymous functions that are passed around, except for `addEventListener`, which will make sure that the `this` value within the handler is the object to which the handler was attached.

E.g.

```
setTimeout(function () { this; /*window*/ }, 10);

document.addEventListener('click', function (e) {  
    e.target; //the clicked DOM element
    this; //the document
});
```

#### When `this` is altered by the API

Using [`Function.prototype.call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Function/bind) or `Function.prototype.apply`, it is possible to specify the object to which `this` will point to during a function execution.

Some libraries (e.g. jQuery) are taking advantage of that feature to make `this` point to an object that is more intuitive, rather than the global object.

E.g.

```
$('#someEl').on('click', function (e) {
    this; //the DOM element that was clicked (not the jQuery wrapper)
});
```

When `this` is altered in such way by the library, there is no other way than looking at the library's documentation to see what `this` will be.

We can read from [jQuery event docs](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-basics/) that:

> In addition to the event object, the event handling function also has
>   access to the DOM element that the handler was bound to via the
>   keyword this.

#### Rewriting your function

Now, here's how you could re-write your function:

```
$(".trigger").click(function () {
    var $this = $(this).toggleClass('toggle'),
        $elementToSlide = $this.closest("td").next().find(".clueless > div"),
        isToggled =  !$this.hasClass('toggle'),
        slideBehavior = isToggled? 'slideUp' : 'slideDown';

    $elementToSlide[slideBehavior]();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure exactly what you're trying to achieve but you can cache `$(this)` whenever it has context.

```
$(".trigger").click(function () {
    var $trigger = $(this);
    if ($trigger.hasClass('toggle')) {
        $trigger.closest("td").next().find(".clueless > div").slideUp();
        $trigger.removeClass('toggle');
    } else {
        $trigger.closest("td").next().find(".clueless > div").slideDown();
        $trigger.addClass('toggle');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to cache `$(this).closest("td").next().find(".clueless > div")` then

```
$(".trigger").click(function () {
    var el = $(this).closest("td").next().find(".clueless > div");
    if ($(this).hasClass('toggle')) {
        el.slideUp();
        $(this).removeClass('toggle');
    } else {
        el.slideDown();
        $(this).addClass('toggle');
    }
});
```

I assume this is what you are going for, it would make sense to cache `$(this)` since you are using it multiple times

```
var $this = $(this);
```

would do it

Comment: @SeanKendle that's an opinion and I feel fine, getting downvoted usually presents an opportunity to learn

Comment: wow im an idiot I cant believe I didnt think to put it inside the click function thanks!